# Sending string in a struct over TCP (c++)

Tags: c++, struct, tcp

I'm working on an server-client structure, where I need to send a strings between the server and client, to do so I create a struct containing an int (packet type) and the string, with I then serialize and send over a tcp connection to the client with then deserialize it.

My problem is that I get the wrong string on the client side, the string on the server side is: "PO-1-25-25\nPO-2-50-50\n", but the string I get on the client side is "\x18=$".

The struct I'm sending (same struct on the client side as well)

```
struct Packet {

unsigned int packet_type;

std::string message;

void serialize(char * data) {
    memcpy(data, this, sizeof(Packet));
}

void deserialize(char * data) {
    memcpy(this, data, sizeof(Packet));
}
};
```

My code for sending the struct:

```
void sendGameStatePacket(unsigned int receiver){


const unsigned int packet_size = sizeof(Packet);
    char packet_data[packet_size];

    Packet packet;
    packet.packet_type = GAME_STATE;
    packet.message = message;


    packet.serialize(packet_data);

    network->sendToOne(packet_data, packet_size, receiver);
}

void sendToOne(char * packets, int totalSize, unsigned int socketID){

SOCKET currentSocket = sessions[socketID];
int iSendResult;    
iSendResult = NetworkServices::sendMessage(currentSocket, packets,totalSize); 

}

int sendMessage(SOCKET curSocket, char * message, int messageSize)
{
    return send(curSocket, message, messageSize, 0);
}
```

Client side code for receiving the struct:

```
char network_data[MAX_PACKET_SIZE]; //MAX_PACKET_SIZE = 1000000

void AClientGame::update()
{
Packet packet;
int data_length = network->receivePackets(network_data);
unsigned int i = 0;
    while (i < (unsigned int)data_length)
    {
        packet.deserialize(&(network_data[i]));
        i += sizeof(Packet);

        FString message;
        message = packet.message.c_str();
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Test: %s"), *message);
    }
}

int receivePackets(char * recvbuf)
{
    iResult = NetworkServices::receiveMessage(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, MAX_PACKET_SIZE);
}

int receiveMessage(SOCKET curSocket, char * buffer, int bufSize)
{
    return recv(curSocket, buffer, bufSize, 0);
}
```

I've already checked that the package.message on the client side is the "\x18=$" string so the problem does not lie in the conversion from string to FString.

My Socket configuration is the following:

Server:

```
network::ServerNetwork::ServerNetwork(void)
{
    // create WSADATA object
    WSADATA wsaData;

    // our sockets for the server
    ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;



    // address info for the server to listen to
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        exit(1);
    }

    // set address information
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;    // TCP connection!!!
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);

    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(1);
    }

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);

    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(1);
    }

    // Set the mode of the socket to be nonblocking
    u_long iMode = 1;
    iResult = ioctlsocket(ListenSocket, FIONBIO, &iMode);

    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("ioctlsocket failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(1);
    }

    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);

    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(1);
    }

    // no longer need address information
    freeaddrinfo(result);

    // start listening for new clients attempting to connect
    iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);

    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Client:

```
ClientNetwork::ClientNetwork()
{
    // create WSADATA object
    WSADATA wsaData;

    // socket
    ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    // holds address info for socket to connect to
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
        *ptr = NULL,
        hints;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        exit(1);
    }



    // set address info
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;  //TCP connection!!!

    //resolve server address and port 
    iResult = getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);

    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(1);
    }

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    for (ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {

        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype,
            ptr->ai_protocol);

        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            exit(1);
        }

        // Connect to server.
        iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);

        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            printf("The server is down... did not connect");
        }
    }



    // no longer need address info for server
    freeaddrinfo(result);



    // if connection failed
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        exit(1);
    }

    // Set the mode of the socket to be nonblocking
    u_long iMode = 1;

    iResult = ioctlsocket(ConnectSocket, FIONBIO, &iMode);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("ioctlsocket failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(1);
    }

    //disable nagle
    char value = 1;
    setsockopt(ConnectSocket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &value, sizeof(value));
}
```

If anyone could explain why it is not working and how to fix it would be a great help

Comment: Please write a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). This is way too much code.

Comment: Don't use structs as network protocols. Use network protocols as network protocols. Define yourself a protocol in octets and write yourself a library to send and receive it. Or use something standard like XDR, XML, ...

Comment: Umm, you never wrote any actual code to serialize or deserialize the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, the expression `sizeof(packet)` will not give you the size of the structure including the string, because the string is most likely just a pointer.

And as the string is just a pointer, the data you copy in the serialization function is not the string but the pointer, and you can't send pointers over a network as they are unique for a single process on a single system.

You have to get the actual size of the string, and then allocate that amount of memory (plus whatever else you need to send) and use that size. And of course since the string can be of variable size, you need to send the actual size of the message as well in a message header.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Packet {

unsigned int packet_type;

std::string message;

void serialize(char * data) {
    memcpy(data, this, sizeof(Packet));
}

void deserialize(char * data) {
    memcpy(this, data, sizeof(Packet));
}
};
```

There is so much wrong with this, it's hard to know where to start. First, how would the caller of `deserialize` know how many bytes to pass it? Second, where's the code to actually serialize the `message`? Where's the code to compute the size of the structure *with the data in it*?

When you "serialize" something, you have to arrange it into a *specific* format of bytes. What is this format? There's no code to convert the message into any particular format at all.

This is code that expects things to work by magic.

If you're going to use TCP, before you write even a single line of code, write out a specification for the protocol you're going to use to exchange data at the byte level. Cover how messages will be delimited, which side will transmit when, and so on. You can look at some existing specifications for things like HTTP and SMTP to see what a specification should look like.

Serialization code should produce the precise byte format the specification calls for. Deserialization code should follow the specification's rules for delimiting messages.

Answer (score 0):

you can make it so that in front of the "string" bytes you add for example two other bytes which would represent the "string" length (how many characters). so length would be `first_byte*256+second_byte`

this would be good for when you would send multiple strings from client to server (or other direction) in a single packet. you then simply calculate offsets.